# C++ Insertion sort on a queue

Tags: c++, sorting, queue, implementation, insertion

I am trying to implement 'Insertion Sort' on two queues without using an array.

> Queue 1 - 4, 5, 11, 8, 3
>
> Queue 2 - 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 11

After the sorting they are as following :

> Queue 1 - 3, 4, 5, 8, 11
>
> Queue 2 - 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11

They get sorted. But I sort the queue like if it was a list. I do not know how to deal with a FIFO structure.

My teacher said that my implementation is alright if it was for a list, but not for queue. I am supposed to use the `push()` and `pop()` functions (already implemented them) and a third queue for assistance. This is my current implementation of the sorting algorithm:

```
void InsertionSort(queue* &left, queue* &right)
{
    int x, i = 0, j;
    queue *p = left;
    while (p)
    {
        x = getElemAt(i, left, right);
        j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && x < getElemAt(j, left, right))
        {
            setElemAt(j + 1, getElemAt(j, left, right), left, right);
            j--;
        }
        setElemAt(j + 1, x, left, right);
        p = p->next;
        i++;
   }
}
```

`getElemAt` and `setElemAt` are additional functions I've written separately. How should I approach the problem of sorting with an additional queue?

Comment: What does "Insertion Sort' on two queues" mean? Insertion sort is usually performed on a single array. Can you give an example input and output, and also specify what the problem with your current code is?

Comment: Well my assignment says that I have 2 queues , that need to be sorted.  The problem with my current code is that I access directly the second and the next elements ,which isn't possible in a Queue ,hence  I need to use a third queue  to assist with the sorting , to store previous /unsorted/sorted elements.  I need to not violate the rule that a Queue   is processed as first input ,first output (FIFO)

Comment: I still don't understand what sorting two queues means. Does it mean to sort each one individually? That doesn't seem to be what the code above does.

Comment: I have 2 queues , left and right. They are being sorted with the code above.

Comment: Yes, you have repeated that several times now, and it is still just as meaningless. How about an example of what the queues contain before and after sorting?

Comment: Queue 1 - 4 ,5 ,11 ,8,3     ,Queue 2 - 2,3,4,5 ,2 ,11.  After the sorting they are as following : Queue 1 - 3 ,4 ,5 ,8,11  , Queue 2 - 2,2,3,4,5,11.  They get sorted. But I sort the queue like if it was a list. I do not know how to deal with a  FIFO structure and I am seeking advice here.

Comment: Ah i see, in my solution I only sorted the first Q and that's pushed into second queue.

Comment: right . My solution works like this too. In the main method , it calls the  InsetionSort function  separately for the first queue and the second queue.

Comment: Okay, deleted my answer, doesn't add any new thoughts.

Comment: Nah  , your answer provided useful information , I think it would have worked in this case  , you could post it again ,if it's not a problem.

Comment: Added queues and results from the comments into the main text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@interjay the queues need to be sorted individualy , with the use of a 3rd assisting queue which is used when queue1 or queue2 is sorted. The queues must not be sorted at the same time because this will require 2 assisting queues

Comment: Or if sorting two queues according to one of the queues, then the third queue can be used for pairs of elements.